# Is it possible to expand a sass mixin?

Tags: sass, mixins

If I have a "button" mixin and I want to add some rules in it, how can i  expand it?
Something like:

```
@mixin button (){
  .....
};

@expand button {
  font-size: 11px;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Mixins cannot be extended or inherited.  You can only overwrite them to have the new behavior.